# Run two watch commands simultaneously

Tags: bash, tail, watch

I want to run two executables in the foreground by typing one line of code or running a shell script. These executables watch a directory and recompile some code while outputting their status to stdout.

I want the stdout to be presented in the same way as following two files in 'tail' like so:

```
tail -f foo.txt -f bar.txt

==> foo.txt <==
Something

==> bar.txt <==
Something else
```

When something changes it prints the filename before printing the output. It only prints the filename when it needs to indicate that the output is coming from the other file.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. I'm not trying to be rude, but I honestly don't know what your question is after reading that.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added some more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Since the two executables write to standard output, you may be able to just `tail` the files produced by process substitution:

```
tail -f <( executable_one ) <( executable_two )
```

(Only one `-f` needed, by the way. It's a global option, not something you need to specify for each file.)

Each of the two executables runs separately, and its output is captured and redirected to a file handle which is passed `tail`. In the output, the file names will appear as something like "/dev/fd/63". Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to get tail to use an alternate name (like with `grep` and the `--label` option).

Answer (score 0):

See this Geek Stuff article: "[3 Methods To View tail -f output of Multiple Log Files in One Terminal](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/multitail-to-view-tail-f-output-of-multiple-log-files-in-one-terminal/)".